# Upgrade conversion

Tags: compatibility

Hello there I just refurbish and converted a Bridgestone  MB -5. I using Shimano Sora flight deck shifters 3x8. Rear derailleur is a Shimano Deore front Shimano Derailleur. Crank is a Silgiovt sp 11/44 - 11/34.

Not shifting as good as I would like in middle range would like to fine a better combination.[image]
Thank You for any help would be grateful .

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example, how exactly shifting is "not good"? and "finding better combination" did you mean a better groupset for 3x8 setup? Which one would you willing to get replace, rear/front derailleurs, shifter?

Comment: Its having trouble shifting up or down in front ring setup. I has hoping to do a 3x8 setup but it seem it won't work that will with the shifters.. So they change the front crank two rings. I would really like to change it to a 2x10 set up shifter,crank, rear deralleru and front and new cgain. comatation.

Comment: Do you have a Shimano Road front derailleur (e.g. Sora) which the crank set specs are within the specs written on the data sheet?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure about the front Derailleu could be.

Comment: Usually the model is printed on parts. A close up photo could also help.